# Improve react performance when filtering an array of over 4000 objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-hooks

I have a component that returns an input of type text that filters an array of over 4000 objects.

```
 const { airports } = useContext(MainContext);
 const [airportListLocal, setAirportListLocal] = useState<Airport[]>(airports);

 useEffect(() => {
    setAirportListLocal(airports);
  }, []);
```

**airports** is a massive array of objects. I get it first through **useContext** . I add it to the local state **(airportListLocal)** to avoid modifying the original airports array. *I think this is what is costing me the performance bottleneck*

```
<input
    type="text"
    name="From"
    className="w-full border rounded-xl h-11 p-4 text-sm focus:border-blue-500 outline-none focus:border-2"
    placeholder="Start your flight search"
    onKeyDown={(e) => searchAirports(e)}
    onChange={(e) => checkIfEmpty(e)}
  />
```

**onKeyDown function** is used to listen when the user completes typing and presses enter.

```
  const searchAirports = (e: React.KeyboardEvent) => {
    const searchValue = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).value.toLowerCase();

    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      const filteredAirports = airportListLocal.filter(
        (airport) =>
          airport.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue) ||
          airport.country.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue) ||
          airport.city.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue)
      );
      setAirportListLocal(filteredAirports);
    }
  };
```

**onChange function** is used to listen if there is no input *meaning the user hasn't typed anything or has deleted everything so that I can show all the results*

```
  const checkIfEmpty = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    if ((e.target as HTMLInputElement).value.length === 0) {
      setAirportListLocal(airports);
    }
  };
```

I map over the current state to show render the data like this

```
<div className="airports-list mt-8 search-results-airports h-28 overflow-y-scroll scroll">
    {airportListLocal.map((airport) => (
      <div key={airport.id} className="flex justify-between">
        <p className="font-bold text-sm">{airport.country}</p>
        <p className="text-xs">{airport.name}</p>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
```

**Problem** **This app is so slow. Ridiculously slow. When the component mounts chrome actually hangs and stops responding. When I type a character in the input the app freezes again.**

I can't figure out what is causing the performance problems.
I don't control the API where I get the data, so I can't get a paged version. Everything comes at once.

**Any suggestions?**

Comment: ^^ or at least after the user has paused typing for, say, 250ms.

Comment: 4000 is relatively small and your filter function should not cause such performance issues. Problem is likely that the function is being run many times as mentioned by other commenters. And limit the items inserted to the DOM.

Comment: You should debounce the filter function so that it only fires after they've stopped typing for a set period. Also if you're rendering thousands items in a list, look at virtualized lists, like this package offers: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized

Comment: The `onKeyDown` only filters if enter is clicked. If it's a rendering problem caused by too many items rendered at once, you can use CSS's `content-visibility` to render only currently displayed items - https://web.dev/content-visibility/

Comment: @Andy do you think the way i add  `airports` as the default state of the `airportsListLocal` has something to do with it ?

Comment: @Andy the onKeyDown function only updates the state if the key is `enter` so i don't understand how that would cause the problems

Answer (score 0):

If your data is paginated, an easier way will be to use [react-infinite-scroll-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-component).

Comment: It isn't paginated